# Ambiguity in processor architecture

Tags: architecture, processor

I wanted to know my processor architecture,and i got it under system information:-

**image**[image]

Now i wanted to check whether I'm 32 bit or 64 bit os. I got confused and helpless when i saw this under system type(x64 based architecture) :-

**image2**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the first screenshot, x86 refers to the fundamental Intel instruction set that has spawned a large family of popular, increasingly complex, architectures:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

MS Windows (in the second screenshot) recognizes that you actually have a 64-bit processor (a Core 2 due 5450 is a 64-bit machine), but lumps some things together into the answer in the first screenshot: yes, this system -- computer **and** OS -- can only run x86 code.  Your version of Windows is a 32-bit version, and your 64-bit machine can execute the 'old' instruction set, most likely without any speed benefit or detriment (there may be some reports on that, if you're so inclined).  Unless (or until) you install a 64-bit OS (not necessarily Windows, either!), you will not be able to run 64-bit programs on your computer.  You may or may not need to, that's up to you.

Comment: so my processor is 64bit then why cant i install or run 64 bit programs.

Comment: can i install 64 bit version of os?

Comment: Plz someone answer to my question and comment.I have not clearly understood

Comment: Yes, you can install the 64-bit version of the OS, since you have a processor that supports it!  Then you will be able to run 64-bit programs.

Comment: last thing to confirm ,so suppose i install 64 bit os,then system type(in first pic) will change from x86 to x64 based pc right?

Comment: That is the behavior I had seen previously; I would assume it would do so on your machine as well.

Comment: @amankhunt Please remember to accept the answer if you found it useful.  Thanks!